# Javafx NullPointerException Label

Tags: javafx-8

I'm trying to build an Inventory Management System in **Javafx** `fxml`. 
I made a login window for users to login. When user login input their user name and password, the login window closes and shows an Admin Panel. The user can see their user name and others which he entries in the Admin Panel.

I successfully passed the date and the Admin Panel can show the user name and id. I can pass the data(id/UserName) from a Controller to another Controller and Show this value in a label.

> It works(Show data in the Label)

```
package controller;
@FXML
private Label lblUserId;
@FXML
private Label lblUsrName;
private userNameMedia usrNameMedia; // java class userNameMedia
public userNameMedia getUsrNameMedia() {
    return usrNameMedia;
}

public void setUsrNameMedia(userNameMedia usrNameMedia) {
    lblUserId.setText(usrNameMedia.getId());
    lblUsrName.setText(usrNameMedia.getUsrName());
    this.usrNameMedia = usrNameMedia;
}
```

> But it gives me null(System output null)

```
package controller;
@FXML
private Label lblUserId;
@FXML
private Label lblUsrName;
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {        
    System.out.println(lblUsrName.getText());
}
```

> Using Button in the same class

```
@FXML
private void btnHomeOnClick(ActionEvent event) {
    homeActive();
    System.out.println(lblUsrName.getText());
    System.out.println(lblUserId.getText());
}
```

It works properly. I need this when usr login `btnHomeOnClick` is clicked.

> Why `System.out.println(lblUsrName.getText());` print `null`

I'm trying to using `initialize` but it returns `null`, I even tried to `fire()`.

To Explore my full code: [Click Here](https://bitbucket.org/kmrifat/javafxproblem/src)

Comment: Can you add the part of the fxml where you have defined `lblUsrName`?

Comment: Post Updated.. i have been added fxml file on bitbucke. please check it out.  @ItachiUchiha